# Encounter an error when I was trying to pratice/learn my first program on springmvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I just started to learn Spring and wrote a Hello Word program for SpringMVC and this error stops me

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
```

I have all the necessary jar files inside lib directory.I am using spring 3.2,tomcat server and eclipse Indigo IDE.

In web.xml I declared dispatcher servlet (named dispatcher) and also, corresponding dispatcher-servlet.xml under web-inf.

Also in web.xml declared listener and under contextConfigLocation /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml.

I searched google but not been able to found any answer.During my search I found something about maven pom.xml (don't know what is that)but not been able to understand what exactly it is?Do I need maven for springmvc?
What will be the solution for this problem?

Comment: verify that `servlet-api.jar` or some amother jar containing `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` is in your classpath.
How you running your program?

Comment: I am running it through eclipse traditional way.I was just started/restarted the server during deployment it gives that error

Comment: still waiting for an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

In which lib directory do you put the JAR files?
If it is inside the WEB-INF directory, it is supposed to be loaded. Otherwise, the JAR files should be imported in the WEB Deployment Assembly as well.

If you would need a step-by-step tutorial at the beginning, you can try to follow [Hello World Example Using Spring Framework MVC 3.1](http://www.flacom.com/hello-world-example-using-spring-framework-mvc-3-1/)